Como obtener el valor de una variable enviada por POST
Tengo un formulario, donde creo con un  foreach los input checkbox según una consulta de  MySQL
QUERY:
$query = 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR \',\') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEME = 'ac_nqn\' and TABLE_NAME = \'usuarios\'';

$resultado = mysqli_query ( $conn, $query );

While($fila = mysqli_fecth_array( $resultado )) {

   $datos = $fila[0];

   $array_datos=explode(",",$datos);
}

Obtengo los resultados y los utilizo para crear los checkbox:
CHECKBOX:
$contador = 0;
foreach ($array_datos as $val_1) {

if($contador > 3){
   echo '<td class="td_checkbox">
           <label>'.$val_1.'</label>
           <input type="checkbox" id="settings-'.$contador.'" name="CHECK'.$val_1.'" value="">
       </td>'
  } $contador ++;
}

Mi duda, yo envio estos datos, segun el  checkbox que se marque o todos, los envio a otro  .php ¿como puedo obtener ese dato  $_POST['']? de manera dinamica, no tener que escribir el valor de manera estandar en el  POST

Podrías explicar más la pregunta?, tengo experiencia en PHP pero no me queda claro, obtienes los datos del check y los envías a otro script PHP, verdad? y quieres cacharlos como? no usando POST? no usando array? probaste con las $_SESSION ? ahi puedes meter valores y los "paseas" por todas partes. No se si entendí bien tu pregunta.

Ya estás recibiendo los valores del arreglo asociativo $_POST[] de manera dinámica, pues no hay otra forma, ya que este se construye con los datos del formulario.
Lo que, probablemente no sabes, es cómo acceder a estos valores sin tener los nombres de las llaves que trae.
En PHP puedes valerte de la función foreach() para construir un ciclo en donde tendrás acceso a las llaves de dicho arreglo y a los valores asociados a dichas llaves (de allí el nombre de arreglo asociativo).
Lo básico aquí sería algo como:
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo("el valor de '$key' es '$value'");
}

Como puedes ver, si ejecutas este script como destino de un formulario con el método POST, en cada iteración, la variable $key va a tener el nombre del campo en el formulario, y la variable $value va a tener el valor que el usuario le dio a dicho campo.
Dado que veo que te interesa particularmente el valor de los inputs de tipo checkbox y que sigues el patrón de nombrarlos "CHECK_XX"  en tu código de ejemplo, he preparado un script de ejemplo que puede servirte de base.
Mi sugerencia es que lo llames primero con un formulario estático como este, al que le vas agregando y quitando campos de manera manual:
<form action="procesarformulario.php" method="post">
  <label>Nombre</label><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"><br>
  <label>Check A</label><input type="checkbox" id="settings-1" name="CHECK_A"><br>
  <label>Check B</label><input type="checkbox" id="settings-2" name="CHECK_B"><br>
  <label>Check C</label><input type="checkbox" id="settings-3" name="CHECK_C"><br>
  <label>Check D</label><input type="checkbox" id="settings-4" name="CHECK_D"><br>
  <label>Check TEST</label><input type="checkbox" id="settings-5" name="CHECK_TEST"><br>
  <button>Enviar</button><br>
</form>

procesarformulario.php
<?php
function startsWith($string, $startString) { 
  $len = strlen($startString); 
  return (substr($string, 0, $len) === $startString); 
} 
$strchecks = "";
$strotros = "";
$nombre_checks = [];
$valor_checks = [];
$checks = [];
$sql1 = "insert into Mitabla (nombre";
$sql2 = "values (?";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (startsWith($key, 'CHECK_')) {
      $strchecks .= "'$key' = '$value'<br>";
      $checks[$key] = $value;
      array_push($valor_checks, $value);
      array_push($nombre_checks, $key);
      $len = strlen($key) - 6;
      $sql1 .= ", ".substr($key, 6, $len);
      $sql2 .= ", ?";
    } else {
        $strotros .= "'$key' = '$value'";
    }
  }
  $sql = $sql1.") ".$sql2.");";
}
?>
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Checks</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
        <div>
            <h2>Valores recibidos</h2>
            <h3>Otros valores:</h3>
            <p><?echo($strotros);?></p>
            <h3>checks:</h3>
            <p><?echo($strchecks);?></p>
            <p><strtong>nombres: </strtong><?print_r($nombre_checks);?></p>
            <p><strtong>valores: </strtong><?print_r($valor_checks);?></p>
            <h3>checks (asociativo):</h3>
            <p><?print_r($checks);?></p>
            <h2>SQL construido</h2>
            <p><?echo($sql);?></p>
        </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>

Estudia el código, en él:

Verifico que el script se halla invocado mediante el verbo POST.
Recorro el arreglo asociativo $_POST[] usando foreach() y, para cada elemento devuelto, verifico si la llave inicia con CHECK_. Si esta condición se cumple hago varias cosas:

Voy dejando en una variable tipo string la llave y el valor, de manera que pueda imprimirse fácilmente para el usuario.
Voy almacenando en los arreglos $nombre_checks y $valor_checks el nombre y su valor asociado, respectivamente. Podría, más adelante, utilizar estos arreglos para procesar la información recibida.
También voy preparando un arreglo asociativo $checks[]. Este se podría recorrer de igual manera que el arreglo _POST[], pero tiene solamente los valores de los checkboxes seleccionados por el usuario.
Finalmente voy construyendo una sentencia SQL de inserción, donde voy dejando la parte relevante de los nombres de estos checks, como si fueran los campos de una base de datos. (Esto es un plus, pues viendo como construyes tu formulario, supongo que vas en esa dirección).


Si la condición no se cumple, soy voy dejando en la variable $strotros los valores para imprimirlos.

Finalmente, muestro la información de estas variables en el documento HTML que se forma como salida.
Te invito a jugar con este código. Primero agrega y quita checkboxes del formulario estático. Luego, modifica el script para que se parezca más a lo que quieres conseguir. Finalmente, sustituye el formulario estático por uno que generes dinámicamente con los campos de tu base de datos.
Esto debería dejarte encarrilado y bastante cerca de la solución que quieres construir.

Estare probando todo esto, pues es la direccion en la que quiero ir.. Muy completo, muy amable!

Puedes hacerlo de varias maneras.
Una de ellas es la manera en la que lo estás haciendo:
<input type="checkbox" id="settings-'.$contador.'" name="CHECK'.$val_1.'" value="">

Y luego, teniendo en cuenta que $_POST no deja de ser un array, podrías acceder a los valores del mismo con un foreach:
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    //$key será el indice (el valor que tenia $val_1)
    //$value será el valor del input, dependiendo de si es un text, un check, etc
}

Otra y mejor que la anterior, sería utilizar arrays en los nombres de los inputs
<input type="checkbox" id="settings-'$contador'" name="CHECKS[]" value="">

o
<input type="checkbox" id="settings-'.$contador.'" name="CHECKS['.$val_1.']" value="">

De esta manera, tendrás un array, como en el primer ejemplo, pero no directamente en $_POST, sino en $_POST['checks'], de manera que no te afectaría a la hora de usar otros inputs.
foreach($_POST['checks'] as $key => $value){
    //$key será el indice (el valor que tenia $val_1)
    //$value será el valor del input, dependiendo de si es un text, un check, etc
}

